# getting a white gloved hand as cursor over image link

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, button, onclick

How do I add an attribute so that when I hover over this image-link, the cursor turns into a white gloved hand? I tried adding "style = cursor: hand" to the html, but that didn't work.

```
var garbageHtml = \"<a> <img class='delete' src='https://d1dxeoyimx6ufk.cloudfront.net/ct/images/c_garbage.gif' style='cursor: hand;' title='Delete Draft' onClick='deleteMyIdeaDraftRequest()'/></a>\";

function deleteMyIdeaDraftRequest(draft_id)
{
    console.log('delete draft');
    BI.ajax_call('ct_xt_delete_my_idea_draft.bix?c=$campaign_id', 'POST', {'draft_id':draft_id}, deleteMyIdeaDraftExecute);

}

function deleteMyIdeaDraftExecute(response_, error_)
{

    // Check if any javascript errors occurred
    if(error_)
    {
        openMessageBox('Server Error', error_);
        return false;
    }

    var deleted_draft_id = response_.responseText;
    var obj_draft = document.getElementById(deleted_draft_id);
    if(obj_draft)
    {
    document.getElementById('my_idea_drafts_container').removeChild(obj_draft);


    }
}
```

Comment: what is the text-link before them? I guess the error is there in the html...

Comment: Need the code of your anchor tag that exists somewhere

Comment: Why don't you wrap the garbageHtml var inside of an anchor ("<a>garbageHtml</a> &nbsp;"),  in the first line of ideaDraftListHtml = ... part before the non-breaking space.

Comment: Better yet, add the anchor to the string where you initialize the garbageHtml.

Comment: Why are you escaping \" all of your strings - it isn't doing what you think it is doing.